# Concurrent Fwrite in PHP?

Tags: php, logging, fwrite

I have a fwrite function to write log for delay insert to the database.

We have a visit rate of 20,000 Visits per hour.

so it's 0.18s per fwrite.

My question is that is it possible that PHP will miss several log when there are 2 or 3 visitor come in at the same time?

If it's then how can I make this concurrent?

My code is just normal Fopen fwrite fclose.

Comment: I did some testing that showed that writes were atomic up to 10k on my platform (centos).  I think most applications rely on this; sometimes you'll end up with a few corrupted log entries, but that's usually more acceptable than adding the overhead of any sort of write synchronization would require.  Maybe you could log to syslog if it's really an issue?

Comment: My code is just a normal fopen fwrite fclose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid this if I was you.  If you must log something for each request, either use something like Gearman to queue the data for later processing, or store it in a database (or a NoSQL db) for later processing.  Don't forget that databases were designed to solve this very problem.  Don't try to re-invent a db using log files.

Not to mention that 0.18s per write is likely a lot more expensive than an insert into a DBM (MySQL for me typically returns writes inside of 0.01 seconds, depending on the table, MongoDB can be a LOT faster).

Comment: Why would you add extra strain on your DB server's harddisk, when there is syslog(3)?

Comment: Mel: because the OP explicitly states that he wants to get this data back for a delayed db operation.  So wouldn't that be an abuse of syslog to use it as a temporary datastore?  I would agree to just use syslog if we were talking about logging, but it appears the OP is just looking for a temporary queue (but I could be wrong)

Comment: Hmm, I read it that he wants to log the "delay time of inserts" i.e. how long an insert takes. Guess OP needs to clarify what he wants.

Comment: Dear Mel, insert using Load Data from our server is only take less than 1 second. We currently use Fwrite to write out temporary CSV, after the CSV reach 500KB we will import it to the database. But we need to keep it correct. At fist I though using gear man, but it's a pain in installation because we are running on windows, so I use Fwrite instead. I guess I should still go back to Gearman to queue the fwrite?

Answer (score 1):

How are you firing off the writes? If each requests (1 per visit) has an associated fwrite with it, you won't miss any. Perhaps they could become slow(er) as your web server is queuing / handling requests (peak traffic), but PHP is request driven, so for every page load, you'll have the fwrite execute.

I say you won't miss any because, unless your doing some non blocking I/O, your script is going to block on the fwrite call. In other words, fwrite will execute.

You're going to have trouble getting any sort of concurrency on a request driven app written in PHP without doing some really funky stuff.